# AngularJS and ExtJS together

Tags: angularjs, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Just learning , new to this site.

Is it possible to have ExtJs and AngularJS together in same application ?

or is it worth to have both of them in same application ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people use ExtJs components in an AngularJS app.
AngularJS is flexible enough to integrate with any other Javascript code/libraries as long as the library has public events to respond to. I would recommend going through the Directive and scope documentation on how to effectively create directives and respond to scope events.

Personally I do not feel ExtJS and AngularJS would be needed together, unless you are forced to use it like me. There is http://angular-ui.github.io/ that brings in a lot to the table. Again any given JQuery plugin can be integrated using directives, filters etc in AngularJS. So you may want to investigate into that before trying to bother with ExtJS.